# Importing separate SVG files to core-iconset

Tags: polymer

I have a bunch of SVG assets I'm currently storing each in their own file for my site. I want to use these SVG files as part of an iconset in polymer, so I can do stuff like `<core-icon icon="tubers:potato">`

The problem is that there seems to be no way to say something like

```
<core-iconset-svg id="tubers">
  <svg id="potato">
    ... import svg file here without copy-paste ...
  </svg> 
</core-iconset-svg>
```

Which effectively means I have to take my SVG resource and wrap the polymer code around it. This isn't the end of the world, strictly speaking, but is is a little annoying (I want to treat SVG files as framework-independent resources like font or PNG resource).

However, the other problem I have found is that if I try to define my icons in different html files with this kind of structure:

```
/tuber-icons
  /tuber-icons.html
  /potato-icon.html
  /parsnip-icon.html
```

and then have a distinct `<core-iconset-svg id="tubers">` inside both icon.html files, and a `<link rel="import">` directive in tuber-icons to bind it all together, it fails. It looks like you can only define a single core-iconset-svg directive with any given id value. This makes sense, but it means I cannot do `icon="tubers:potato"`, but instead need to have a different top-level namespace for each icon.

The alternative is to concatenate all the SVG files into one big file, but that feels even worse, when it comes to copypasta errors, since then I end up with One Big File, which also has lots of copy-pasta'd SVG directives, each of which needs to be slightly massaged to fit the polymer process.

So, back to the question: is there any reasonable way to import an existing SVG directive that I'm serving as a static resource into a polymer core-iconset-svg directive?